# Office.js Outlook Add-in - Can I add an icon to an appointment's block in the calendar view?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm playing around with creating an Outlook Add-In. I'm looking through their own developer guides and API documentation to get a sense of what can be achieved. And how.

As a part of my simple plugin, I'd like to decorate the blocks in the calendar view with a status-icon. Similar to how an even can have the icon to indicate that it's reoccuring or that it has files attached:

[image]

However, I haven't been able to find any method or information about how to do this - if it's possible at all.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this feature does not exist for Outlook Web Add-ins. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for giving me a precise answer to this. Even though it wasn't what I had hoped for :)